# Timers cannot be stopped from another thread Qt

Tags: multithreading, qt, qt5, qthread, qtimer

I am working on Qt application. There I am using two threads, one for the GUI and one for do the processing.

I have worker class which has QTimer as member class.

.h file:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QThread>

class Worker : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
 public:
  Worker();
  QTimer t;
 public slots:
  void process();
  void startWorker();
};

namespace Ui {
 class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT

  public:
   explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
   ~MainWindow();

 private:
   QThread workerThread;
   Worker wt;
 };

 #endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

cpp file

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <iostream>

Worker::Worker() : t(this)
{
 connect(&t, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(process()));
}

void Worker::process()
{
  std::cout << "triggering timer" << std::endl;
}

void Worker::startWorker()
{
  t.start(1000);
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
  QMainWindow(parent)
{
  wt.moveToThread(&workerThread);
  qDebug() << "worker thread " << wt.thread();
  qDebug() << "timer thread " << wt.t.thread();
  connect(&workerThread, SIGNAL(started()), &wt, SLOT(startWorker()));
  connect(&workerThread, &QThread::finished, &workerThread, &QObject::deleteLater);
  workerThread.start();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
 workerThread.quit();
 workerThread.wait();
}
```

I can start the thread with no error. However when I close the application I am getting warning message.

```
QObject::killTimer: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread 
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
```

If QTimer is child of worker class and it has been moved to thread why Qt is complaining about stopping it from different thread?
Note: I have added logs to print thread id and it outputs same value in both cases:

```
worker thread  QThread(0x72fdf0)
timer thread  QThread(0x72fdf0)
```

Can someone please explain? I do not understand what it's happening here

Thanks in advance

Comment: please provide a [mcve] :-)

Comment: what is *that warning message*?

Comment: @eyllanesc "QObject::killTimer: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread"

Comment: I recommend placing that message in your question

Comment: The timer is stopped on destruction, not when the thread quits. As the worker is a member of your main window, this happens as soon as main is exited, leading to that error

Comment: @RuLoViC Obviously I have tested it, you can find my test code in the following link https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/53288644 . Maybe I forgot to point something out, try it and let me know.

Comment: I have copied your code. This is the output "triggering timer
QObject::killTimer: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
ASSERT failure in QCoreApplication::sendEvent: "Cannot send events to objects owned by a different thread. Current thread 0x0x1f9a0580. Receiver '' (of type 'Worker') was created in thread 0x0x72fdf0", file kernel\qcoreapplication.cpp, line 576"

Comment: @RuLoViC Well, in Qt 5.11.2 it works correctly, maybe my solution is only correct for current versions, what version of Qt do you have?

Comment: Qt 5.11.2. I have tested on windows & mac

Comment: Could you try my code? https://github.com/rulovic/TimersAndThreads/tree/master/ThreadTimer/ThreadTimer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally was able to fix the error by:

1. Converting QTimer to pointer
2. Adding slot stopWorker as suggested by @Amfasis
3. In that slot not only stop QTimer but also delete it

Thanks all

Comment: If you instantiate the QTimer with a pointer to your worker (as parent) I would say you shouldn't need to delete. Also make sure to instantiate again if you start the worker again

Answer (score 2):

You should stop the timer before QObject deletes it itself

in .h file, add the destructor:

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Worker();
    ~Worker();
private:
    QTimer t;
public slots:
    void process();
    void startWorker();
    void stopWorker(); //this line was added
};
```

in .cpp file, add:

```
Worker::stopWorker()
{
    t.stop();
}
```

and in constructor

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ...
    connect(&workerThread, &QThread::finished, &wt, &Worker::stopWorker); //add this line!
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should new your timer in your task object slot, not in the task construtor. Stop the timer when your task object is deleted.

My task object header: Worker.h

```
#pragma once
#include <QObject>
class QTimer;

class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Worker(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~Worker();

public slots:
    void WorkerTaskStartSlot(void);
    void TaskFinished(void);
private slots:
    void TimerOutToDoSomethingSlot(void);
signals:
    void WorkertResultSig(void);

private:
    QTimer *m_pTimer = nullptr;
};
```

Worker.cpp:

```
#include "Worker.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>
#include <QTimer>

Worker::Worker(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    qDebug()<<__FUNCTION__<<"threadid"<< QThread::currentThreadId();

}

Worker::~Worker()
{
    TaskFinished();
      qDebug()<<__FUNCTION__<<"threadid"<< QThread::currentThreadId();
}


void Worker::WorkerTaskStartSlot(void)
{
    qDebug()<<__FUNCTION__<<"threadid"<< QThread::currentThreadId();
    emit WorkertResultSig();

    m_pTimer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(m_pTimer,&QTimer::timeout,this,&Worker::TimerOutToDoSomethingSlot);
    m_pTimer->start(1000);
}


void Worker::TaskFinished(void)
{
    qDebug()<<__FUNCTION__<<"threadid"<< QThread::currentThreadId();

    if(m_pTimer)
    {
        if(m_pTimer->isActive())
        {
            m_pTimer->stop();
            qDebug()<<__FUNCTION__<<"stop timer"<< QThread::currentThreadId();
        }

        delete m_pTimer;
        m_pTimer = nullptr;
    }
}


void Worker::TimerOutToDoSomethingSlot(void)
{
    qDebug()<<__FUNCTION__<<"threadid"<< QThread::currentThreadId();
}
```

The controller header: MainWindow.h

```
#pragma once

#include <QMainWindow>
class QPushButton;
class QWidget;
class Worker;
class QThread;

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
private:
    void InitCtrl(void);
private slots:
    void StartTaskBtnSlot(const bool &checked);
    void WorkertResultSlot(void);
private:
    QPushButton *m_pStartTaskBtn = nullptr;
    QWidget *m_pCenterWidget = nullptr;
    Worker *m_pWorker = nullptr;
    QThread *m_pWorkerThread = nullptr;
};
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>
#include "Worker.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    InitCtrl();
    qDebug()<<__FUNCTION__<<"mainwindow thread id"<< QThread::currentThreadId();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}

void MainWindow::InitCtrl(void)
{
    m_pCenterWidget = new QWidget(this);
    m_pStartTaskBtn = new QPushButton(QStringLiteral("Start"),this);

    QVBoxLayout *pvertlayout = new QVBoxLayout();
    pvertlayout->addWidget(m_pStartTaskBtn);
    m_pCenterWidget->setLayout(pvertlayout);

    setCentralWidget(m_pCenterWidget);

    m_pStartTaskBtn->setCheckable(true);
    connect(m_pStartTaskBtn,&QPushButton::clicked,this,&MainWindow::StartTaskBtnSlot);

}

void MainWindow::StartTaskBtnSlot(const bool &checked)
{
    if(checked)
    {
        m_pStartTaskBtn->setText(QStringLiteral("Close"));

        m_pWorkerThread = new QThread();
        m_pWorker = new Worker();

        // move the task object to the thread BEFORE connecting any signal/slots
        m_pWorker->moveToThread(m_pWorkerThread);

        connect(m_pWorkerThread, SIGNAL(started()), m_pWorker, SLOT(WorkerTaskStartSlot()));
        connect(m_pWorker, SIGNAL(WorkertResultSig()), this, SLOT(WorkertResultSlot()));

        // automatically delete thread and task object when work is done:
        connect(m_pWorkerThread, SIGNAL(finished()), m_pWorker, SLOT(deleteLater()));
        connect(m_pWorkerThread, SIGNAL(finished()), m_pWorkerThread, SLOT(deleteLater()));


        m_pWorkerThread->start();
    }
    else
    {
        m_pStartTaskBtn->setText(QStringLiteral("Start"));
        m_pWorkerThread->quit();
        m_pWorkerThread->wait();
    }
}

void MainWindow::WorkertResultSlot(void)
{
    qDebug()<<__FUNCTION__<<"threadid"<<QThread::currentThreadId();

}
```

Finally, it will output result like this:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow mainwindow thread id 0x2bf0
Worker::Worker threadid 0x2bf0
Worker::WorkerTaskStartSlot threadid 0x4af0
MainWindow::WorkertResultSlot threadid 0x2bf0
Worker::TimerOutToDoSomethingSlot threadid 0x4af0
Worker::TimerOutToDoSomethingSlot threadid 0x4af0
Worker::TimerOutToDoSomethingSlot threadid 0x4af0
Worker::TimerOutToDoSomethingSlot threadid 0x4af0
Worker::TaskFinished threadid 0x4af0
Worker::TaskFinished stop timer 0x4af0
Worker::~Worker threadid 0x4af0
```